# Django Template Regroup Unexpected Result

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have a view that looks like this:

```
def CarteleraPeliculaToday(request, slugpelicula):
    city = request.session["ciudad"]
    today = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=5)).date()  # date: Ecuador time zone
    pelicula = Pelicula.objects.get(slug=slugpelicula)
    espanol_3d_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, gtmax=1)
    espanol_3d = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1)
    espanol_3d_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, vip=1)
    espanol_3d_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", tipo_3d=1, xd=1)
    espanol_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", gtmax=1)
    espanol = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol")
    espanol_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", vip=1)
    espanol_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Espanol", xd=1)
    subtitulada_3d_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, gtmax=1)
    subtitulada_3d = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1)
    subtitulada_3d_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, vip=1)
    subtitulada_3d_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", tipo_3d=1, xd=1)
    subtitulada_gtmax = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", gtmax=1)
    subtitulada = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada")
    subtitulada_vip = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", vip=1)
    subtitulada_xd = Funcion.objects.filter(fecha_inicio__lte=today, fecha_fin__gte=today, idpelicula__slug=slugpelicula, idciudad=city, visible=1, idioma="Subtitulada", xd=1)

    #Creating a dictionary of all types of funciones querysets
    funciones = {'espanol': espanol, 'subtitulada': subtitulada, 'espanol_3d': espanol_3d, 'subtitulada_3d': subtitulada_3d, 'espanol_3d_gtmax': espanol_3d_gtmax,
'espanol_vip': espanol_vip, 'espanol_xd': espanol_xd, 'subtitulada_3d_gtmax': subtitulada_3d_gtmax,  'subtitulada_3d_vip': subtitulada_3d_vip,  'espanol_3d_vip': espanol_3d_vip, 'espanol_3d_xd': espanol_3d_xd, 'espanol_gtmax': espanol_gtmax,
'subtitulada_3d_xd': subtitulada_3d_xd, 'subtitulada_gtmax': subtitulada_gtmax, 'subtitulada_vip': subtitulada_vip, 'subtitulada_xd': subtitulada_xd}

    #Removing empty element from funciones dictionary
    for x in list(funciones.keys()):
        if not (funciones[x]).exists():
            del funciones[x]

    context = {'pelicula': pelicula, 'funciones': funciones}
    return render_to_response('cartelera-pelicula.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Example(from ipdb):

```
(Pdb) funciones
{'espanol_3d_gtmax': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_3d_vip': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_3d_xd': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_xd': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_vip': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_3d': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol': [<Funcion: American Junkie, Funcion #9: Sebas el Genio>, <Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>], 'espanol_gtmax': [<Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>]}
<type 'dict'>
```

Now accessing a value:

```
funciones['espanol']
[<Funcion: American Junkie, Funcion #9: Sebas el Genio>, <Funcion: ted, Funcion #15: Sebas el Genio>]
type(funciones['espanol'])
<class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>
```

And finally accessing an item from the Queryset:

```
(Pdb) funciones['espanol'][0]
<Funcion: American Junkie, Funcion #9: Sebas el Genio>
type(funciones['espanol'][0])
<class 'core_app.models.Funcion'>
```

Now, my template looks like this:

```
{% for key,value in funciones.items %}
    {% regroup value by idcine as cine_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for c in cine_list %}
        <li>{{ c.grouper }}</li>
        <ul>
            {% for item in cine_list %} 
               <li>{{key}}:{{item}}</li>   
            {% endfor %}    
        </ul></li>  
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

The output I get with this:

```
Supercines Quicentro Sur

espanol_3d_gtmax:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}

Supercines Quicentro Sur

espanol_3d_vip:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}

Supercines Quicentro Sur

espanol_3d_xd:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}

Multicines CCI
espanol_3d:{'list': [<Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #16: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Multicines CCI>}
espanol_3d:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}

Supercines Quicentro Sur
espanol_3d:{'list': [<Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #16: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Multicines CCI>}
espanol_3d:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}

Multicines Recreo
subtitulada_vip:{'list': [<Funcion: Multicines Recreo, Funcion #28: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Multicines Recreo>}

Multicines CCI
espanol:{'list': [<Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #16: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Multicines CCI>}
espanol:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}
```

And what I would to get instead would be something like this:

```
Supercines Quicentro Sur
espanol_3d_gtmax:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}
espanol_3d_vip:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}
espanol_3d_xd:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}

Multicines CCI
espanol_3d:{'list': [<Funcion: Multicines CCI, Funcion #16: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Multicines CCI>}
espanol:{'list': [<Funcion: Supercines Quicentro Sur, Funcion #27: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Supercines Quicentro Sur>}

Multicines Recreo
subtitulada_vip:{'list': [<Funcion: Multicines Recreo, Funcion #28: Intouchables>], 'grouper': <Cine: Multicines Recreo>}
```

Any ideas on what I should change to get my desired output?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your `regroup` line try `dictsort`ing it first:

```
{% regroup value|dictsort:"idcine" by idcine as cine_list %}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion, I tried it and it doesn't seem to be making a difference.

Comment: I actually ended up having to modify what my view returned in order to accomplish what I needed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.